# Give Baby Items

Tags: tomodachi-life

How can you make a baby into a kid? I really want to give it an Age O Matic, but there's no way to give it items because the game doesn't have a mode to interact with it other than Babysit mode, which I've pretty much *not* mastered.

Comment: Sorry! The baby can be comforted now, I figured out the pattern. But I still need help giving it the Age O Matic.

Comment: Can you edit your question (remove any irrelevant parts, don't just strike them out) to make it clear what you still need help with, if anything? Try to focus on a single question.

Comment: I think it's because you can't actually interact with it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait until the baby grows up before you can give them items such an Age-o-matic. It takes about 3-7 days for the baby to grow up into a normal Mii.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I've missed anything or if something in the answer is wrong.